# StoreKit crashes after second request and buy product

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I'm having trouble with In-App Purchases. The app is crashing in the following case:

1. Opening the view from NavController
2. Requesting the 2 SKProducts
3. Showing price of products on the labels
4. Closing View by going back in NavController
5. Opening the view from NavController again
6. Requesting the 2 SKProducts
7. Showing price of products on the labels
8. Buying one product with `SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)`
9. Crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

I've checked that the payment isn't nil. If I buy the product on the first open everything is working as it should. Any tips why it crashes only in this case?

Here is the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)

    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments(){
        print("Enabled, Loading...")
        let productId: NSSet = NSSet(objects: unlockPremiumId, disableAdsId)
        let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productId as! Set<String>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        print("Please Enable IAP")
    }
}

var SKProductList = [SKProduct]()
var currentSKProduct  = SKProduct()

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    let myProducts = response.products
    for product in myProducts {
        if product.productIdentifier == unlockPremiumId {
            if let productPrice = priceStringForProduct(item: product) {
                premiumFeaturesBtn.setTitle(selectedLanguage.IAPPurchase + productPrice, for: .normal)
            }
        }
        if product.productIdentifier == disableAdsId {
            if let productPrice = priceStringForProduct(item: product) {
                disableAdsBtn.setTitle(selectedLanguage.IAPPurchase + productPrice, for: .normal)
            }
        }
        SKProductList.append(product)
    }
    disableAdsBtn.isEnabled = true
    premiumFeaturesBtn.isEnabled = true
    restoreBtn.isEnabled = true
}

@IBAction func disableAdsTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    disableAdsBtn.isEnabled = false
    for product in SKProductList {
        let ProdId = product.productIdentifier
        if ProdId == disableAdsId {
            buyProduct(skpayment:SKPayment(product: product))
        }
    }
}

func buyProduct(skpayment:SKPayment) {

    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(product)
}
```

Here is the Stack Trace, sorry for the formatting:

- thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)
  frame #0: 0x00000001108c394b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 11
  frame #1: 0x000000011011b4cc StoreKit`__NotifyObserverAboutChanges + 66
  frame #2: 0x000000011289b268 CoreFoundation`CFArrayApplyFunction + 72
  frame #3: 0x000000011011b473 StoreKit`-[SKPaymentQueue _notifyObserversAboutChanges:sendUpdatedDownloads:] + 148
  frame #4: 0x0000000110119951 StoreKit`-[SKPaymentQueue addPayment:] + 313
- frame #5: 0x000000010f57c2a8 AnatomyQuizz`SettingsInAppPurchasesTableViewController.buyProduct(product=0x00006040000086c0, self=0x00007fbcbb090e00) at SettingsInAppPurchasesTableViewController.swift:114
  frame #6: 0x000000010f57b9ac AnatomyQuizz`SettingsInAppPurchasesTableViewController.disableAdsTapped(sender=0x00007fbcba473700, self=0x00007fbcbb090e00) at SettingsInAppPurchasesTableViewController.swift:88
  frame #7: 0x000000010f57bc3c AnatomyQuizz`@objc SettingsInAppPurchasesTableViewController.disableAdsTapped(_:) at SettingsInAppPurchasesTableViewController.swift:0
  frame #8: 0x0000000114a57972 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
  frame #9: 0x0000000114bd6c3c UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
  frame #10: 0x0000000114bd6f59 UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
  frame #11: 0x0000000114bd5e86 UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
  frame #12: 0x0000000115047bad UIKit`_UIGestureEnvironmentSortAndSendDelayedTouches + 5560
  frame #13: 0x0000000115041a4d UIKit`_UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 1506
  frame #14: 0x000000011504141f UIKit`-[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 484
  frame #15: 0x00000001150404cb UIKit`-[UIGestureEnvironment _updateGesturesForEvent:window:] + 288
  frame #16: 0x0000000114acef14 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4102
  frame #17: 0x0000000114a72365 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
  frame #18: 0x00000001153bea1d UIKit`**dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2809
  frame #19: 0x00000001153c1672 UIKit`__handleEventQueueInternal + 5957
  frame #20: 0x00000001128f0101 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
  frame #21: 0x000000011298ff71 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
  frame #22: 0x00000001128d4a19 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
  frame #23: 0x00000001128d3fff CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1279
  frame #24: 0x00000001128d3889 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
  frame #25: 0x00000001192c99c6 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 62
  frame #26: 0x0000000114a565d6 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
  frame #27: 0x000000010f6ac0f7 AnatomyQuizz`main at AppDelegate.swift:15
  frame #28: 0x0000000117907d81 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
  frame #29: 0x0000000117907d81 libdyld.dylib`start + 1

Comment: Which line does it crash on?

Comment: on the `SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)` on the `buyProduct()` function

Comment: You should pass the product to purchase to `buyProduct` as an argument. My guess is that `currentSKProduct` is nil, but the declaration of this property isn't shown

Comment: I've tried it as it is now. It still doesn't work...

Comment: You need to provide more information on the crash; the exception message and a stack trace.

Comment: I've updated the post with the stack trace.
thanks for your patience, btw

Comment: It looks like you payment queue transaction observer has been released. How do you set up your transaction observer?

Comment: As you can see in the code, i declare it in `viewDidLoad`, here: `SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)`